# Memory consumption by SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, memory

SQLite on Android allows you to specify that your databse is "in-memory" by passing null for the database name [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#SQLiteOpenHelper%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int%29)

My question now is related to memory usage: does this use up my precious heap memory that is allowed for my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your sqlite database is dynamically allocated, yes it's stored on the heap.

Comment: good to know, thanks! do you know btw whether query results duplicate the amount of memory used? for example if I "select *" from my table would that use roughly twice the amount of memory?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not certain about that. I'd hope they'd implement it efficiently so that it did. You could try looking at the android source code if you were really really curious.